# How can I use a Gaussian Mixture Model to segment an image by wavelength?

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have an image of a pond (grass, rocks along the edge, water). I'd like to use a GMM as an unsupervised classifier to segment the image into grass, rock, and water.

The image is in the form of a numpy array with shape (800, 800, 4), where each pixel contains intensity data for 4 wavelengths. For example, pixel x=1 y=1 has intensity data [1000, 2000, 1500, 4000] corresponding to wavelengths [450, 500, 600, 700].

I tried to fit a GMM using scikit-learn:

```
gmm=GaussianMixture(n_components=3, covariance_type="tied")
gmm=gmm.fit(data)
```

However, I got an error saying that the expected dimension of the data should be less than or equal to 2.

Are there any Python packages or functions available that can fit a GMM to higher dimensional data?

Comment: how much information do you lose by performing a transformation to the 4 values to reduce them - essentially converting it to a grayscale image?

Comment: This data is already reduced from 150 bands to 4 bands using PCA. I was thinking Self Organized Mapping as well to convert to a 2d array, but my adviser is adamant about GMM on this current array.

Comment: It's unclear what the dimensions of your `data` array correspond to. The `.fit` method of `GaussianMixture` (like every other estimator in scikit-learn) expects an `(n_samples, n_features)` array as the first argument. Does each row in your `(800, 800, 4)` array correspond to a sample? Or is `data` just a single 800x800x4 image?

Comment: Ah sorry for being unclear the data is just data is 800pixel x 800pixel x 4 wavelength bands deep. So it can be thought of as a cube and at each point in the cube is an integer value related to intensity. Does this help? In GaussianMixtures n_samples refers to the dimensionality of the gaussian and n_features refers to the number of means I am expecting correct?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. GMM takes a bunch of samples and fits a probability distribution to them. In your dataset, what constitutes a single sample, and what should the probability distribution be over? For example, you might choose to treat individual pixels as samples and then try to cluster them according to their 4 wavelength values. In that case you would reshape your input array to `(800*800, 4)` (throwing away the information about the spatial arrangement of the pixels).

Comment: Ah, so assign pixels pixel no 1,2,3.....800*800? Instead of a unique X,Y value to each pixel?

Comment: I think the best way to understand the data is as 4 images stacked upon one another

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, what @chase said would work provided that I don't lose any information when I convert to a grayscale image. How would I go about this?

Comment: Again, you need to decide what you consider to be samples and features. You *could* treat each pixel as a sample drawn from a 4-dimensional distribution over wavelengths, and then fit a GMM to this distribution. In that case all you'd need to do is collapse the `data` array over the first two dimensions so that its shape was `(640000, 4)` rather than `(800, 800, 4)`. Would this make sense in your case? I can't tell from your description. What *question* are you trying to answer by fitting a GMM to this data? Could you edit your question to explain?

Comment: Basically I have an image of a pond (grass, rocks along the edge, water), the image is 800 pixels in y and 800 pixels in x, each pixel contains data from 4 important wavelengths for example pixel x=1 y=1 has data [1000,2000, 1500,4000] corresponding to wavelengths [450,500,600,700]. I wish to use gmm as an unsupervised classifier to segment the grass from the rock from the water. I really appreciate your help on this. Thank you for being patient with me and persistent with the problem.

Comment: So I suppose I could reduce the dimension of the matrix from (800,800,4) to (880*800,4) provided that after the gmm is finished I could reconstruct the classified image.

Comment: Would you mind editing your question so it includes the actual problem description? That's essential information, so it shouldn't be buried down here in the comments.

Comment: Edited. Thank you

Comment: Don't cross-post: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/19405/924

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So all I needed to do was collapse the array over the x,y dimensions and the `GMM.fit` method accepted my array input. The original data was in format (800,800,4), and I reshaped it to an (800*800, 4) array.

The code for GMM fitting and clustering is as follows:

```
newdata = img_data.reshape(800*800, 4)
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=3, covariance_type="tied")
gmm = gmm.fit(newdata)

cluster = gmm.predict(newdata)
cluster = cluster.reshape(800, 800)
imshow(cluster)
```

I chose `n_components=3` because I was expecting to segment 3 different types of material (rock, grass, water).

Comment: If you want to see how the clustered/segmented image looks like, use `plt.imshow(gmm.means_[cluster])`, this will project the means of the gaussians back to the image pixels, instead of the cluster index (which makes no sense visually)